# Add comments to Excel pivot slicer options

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

In one Excel pivot table slicer I have almost 50 options. I have given codes to each slicer option rather than writing the entire description about the slicer option.

I am looking to right click/hover over a particular slicer to see the entire description.

Say I have abbreviated one of the options in slicer as 'SOFAA'

On hovering over/right clicking 'SOFAA' I should be able to read a comment 'Stack overflow friends are awesome'.

Comment: To be clear, the 50+ options are slices themselves, not 50+ options for *which* to put the slicer on?  I.e. when you create a slicer, the first option is to choose a category to "slice".  *Then* you have the list of various slicers.

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, say I click on Slicer option in pivot table. I get one box. In that box there are 50+ options. I can click on any one option and I can get data/plots updated. Say it is years: 2015, 2016, 2017. If I click on 2015, the data gets updated. This is what I meant. I apologize if it is not very clear still.

Comment: When we click on Pivot table, we see In the Analyze tab "Insert slicer". This gives the box for slicer. When I click inside the content of the box, there are many options I can select or deselect. I want to add comments on these options. Not on the huge box itself. Hope this makes it clear. I apologize again if not clear.

Comment: In [this .gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds7jr.gif), are you looking to show the comment in the first part (where I select `SOFAA`), or the second part when the slices are showing (2001/2002/2003)?  You're looking to add comments to the first part, yeah?

Comment: Hi Bruce, awesome gif. Yes, I am looking to add comments to the first part. However, you have made some marvelous gif! Can it also be known how to add comments to the second part? This is outstanding!! :)

Comment: This is tricky - I've been playing around with the VBA for PivotTables, and it doesn't seem like there's a built-in way to do this.  My thinking is you're going to instead want to create a UserForm that pops up, shows the options (which can likely have comments), then from *there*, create the slicer.  I know you have many options (50+) but perhaps a quick and dirty solution is just to create a table of abbreviations, and their meaning, and show that in a MessageBox before the slicer, or even on a separate sheet?  That'd be much easier to code I'd think.

Comment: Hi Bruce, Thanks a ton for the reply. I will take your suggestion for it. Yes, this is indeed super tricky one. I will follow your suggestion for it. Again thanks for the reply. Happy Holidays :)